# How to populate a many-to-many relationship as table

Tags: symfony

For my project (hotel website) I have two entities Room & Week and a many-to-many relationship between them with two additionals fields:

- price: Price for a room and a week
- number: Number of room available for a week

I would like to create a form to allow the admin to see/change all price/number in a single table like this:
[image]

Price & number are text fields.

Is there a known way to generate this with Symfony or do you know a bundle?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I did it by myself, I did:

- Create the HTML table
- In each cell I create twi fields like myfield[XX][price] && myfield[XX][number] and after I get all POST data to update my database if needed. With XX a DB id

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

if i read it well your database setup is bad. A week is not an entity but a period of time! you could make an entity with a name like 'RoomOffer' where you have fields like starttime, stoptime, price and room. the room field is then a many-to-many or a many-to-one relation...

Then your table shows lot's of the same forms (each cell). You could use a collection for that.http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html
Be warned: its advanced.

Comment: Actually I did something simple for the question because a week is also use for many other things like staff agenda, activities proposed etc.... and I needed to have a common entity between all.

I check form_collections, thanks